# "Could not deduce" error on multi-parameter type class

Tags: haskell, ghc, typeclass

I have this code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
import System.Random (RandomGen(..))

class RandomGen gen => Shadow gen light where
    shadowRay :: gen -> light -> Float
    eval      :: light -> Float
```

and I get that error:

> ```
> [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( problem.hs, problem.o )
>
> problem.hs:6:5: error:
>     * Could not deduce (Shadow gen0 light)
>       from the context: Shadow gen light
>         bound by the type signature for:
>                    eval :: Shadow gen light => light -> float -> float
>         at problem.hs:6:5-40
>       The type variable `gen0' is ambiguous
>     * In the ambiguity check for `eval'
>       To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
>       When checking the class method:
>         eval :: forall gen light.
>                 Shadow gen light =>
>                 forall float. light -> float -> float
>       In the class declaration for `Shadow'
> ```

This is problem from GHC 7.10+. Before it was working. There is a fix if I add "gen" parameter to "eval", like:

`eval      :: gen -> light -> Float`

But I don't want to add a new value parameter which will not be used. Is there some kind of other way for type resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `eval` does not use `gen`, and so specialising its type is not enough to decide which `gen` to use when picking the `Shadow` instance to use. One possible solution is using a [functional dependency](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#functional-dependencies) to enforce that there will be only one `gen` for each choice of `light`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}

class RandomGen gen => Shadow gen light | light -> gen where
    shadowRay :: gen -> light -> Float
    eval      :: light -> Float
```

It is possible, however, that you don't want or need to couple `light` and `gen` in this manner. In that case, you might want to consider the opposite alternative of removing `gen` from the type class -- if `gen` and `light` aren't related, you don't need a multi-parameter type class to relate them:

```
class Shadow light where
    shadowRay :: RandomGen gen => gen -> light -> Float
    eval      :: light -> Float
```

Comment: Eurika! Yes, I have no relationship between gen and light, so the second variant is my actual fix. 
Thank you very much for the detailed answer!