# Could not deduce … from the Context error

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I have the following two modules, where `QueueA` is an instance of `Queue`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts #-}

module Queue where

class Queue a b where
    empty :: a
    (|>) :: a -> b -> a
    null :: a -> Bool
    head :: a -> b
    tail :: a -> a
    toList :: a -> [b]
```

---

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts #-}

module QueueA where 

import Queue

data QueueA b = QA {front :: [b], frontSize :: Int, rear :: [b], rearSize :: Int}

instance Queue (QueueA b) b where    

    empty = QA [] 0 [] 0

    (|>) (QA f fSize r rSize) el = norm $ QA f fSize (el : r) (rSize + 1)

    null (QA _ 0 _ 0) = True
    null _ = False

    head (QA a _ _ _) = Prelude.head a            

    tail (QA f fSize r rSize) = norm $ QA (Prelude.tail f) (fSize - 1) r rSize      

    toList (QA f _ r _) =  f ++ (reverse r)
```

It compiles, but when I try to use empty I get

```
Could not deduce (Queue a b0)
from the context (Queue a b)
  bound by the inferred type for ‘it’: Queue a b => a
  at <interactive>:113:1-5
The type variable ‘b0’ is ambiguous
When checking that ‘it’ has the inferred type
  it :: forall a b. Queue a b => a
Probable cause: the inferred type is ambiguous
```

And now I just don't know why it can't determine the type of the elements.
What do I need to change?

Comment: You might have several distinct instances with the same `a` and different `b`s. Hence, `empty :: a` is inherently ambiguous. Maybe you want to add a functional dependency `class Queue a b | a -> b where ...`.

Comment: Note that the suggested question starts from the solution for your problem (adding a functional dependency) and explains why it is necessary.

Comment: See also: [*“Could not deduce” error on multi-parameter type class*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41592832/2751851) (unlike the asker there, you need something like the first solution in the answer, rather than the second one).